# Compact Subset in $C[0,1]$

Tags: analysis, compactness, sequence-of-function, function-spaces

Let $S=\{f\in C[0,1]:\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}(|f|+|f'|)\leq M\}$. Show that $S$ is compact in $C[0,1]$.

I have proved that any sequence in $S$ contains a convergent subsequence by Arzela Ascoli theorem,

but my question is: How can I check that the subsequence converges to the point in $S$ and thus prove that $S$ is compact(sequentially compact)?

Comment: Should not it be $C^1[0,1]$?

Comment: Oh! That's typo. The function in $S$ should be differentiable but it is in the space of continuous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of approach this problem is the following. First prove that

$$||f||:=\max_{x\in [0,1]}(|f(x)|+|f'(x)|)$$

is a norm on $C^1[0,1]$ that is equivalent to the usual supremum norm $||f||_{\infty}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$. This implies that the topologies induced by these norms are the same.

Now $S$ is precisely the closed ball $B(0,M)$ in the topology induced by $||\cdot||$, which is compact as it is closed and bounded (this is an equivalent to the sequential definition for compactness in metric spaces as you probably know).

Comment: How can I use this norm since the whole space is $C^0[0,1]$ that some of the functions are not differentiable?

Comment: This has to be a typo, the whole space must be $C^1[0,1]$. Mostafa Ayaz already commented about that and you said it was indeed a typo.